# How to reset Windows 7 Firewall in SafeMode?

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall

In attempt to block the certain countries from hitting my personal computer, I have made a big mistake of adding thousands of block rules in the Windows Firewall.  I got the script from http://www.sans.org/windows-security/2011/10/25/windows-firewall-script-block-addresses-network-ranges.

Now, my PC is taking forever to boot up, it hangs up on Welcome screen.  I am able to boot Windows in a SafeMode (without networking enabled), but then I can not access Firewall service in order to delete these rules.

Any suggestion on how to reset Windows Firewall rules from SafeMode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps those Chinese hackers got to you first!

Or try this:

Stop the Firewall (if it isnt):

- Click on Start menu, and select Control Panel.
- Select Administrative Tools
- Double-click Services option
- In Services console, find and right-click Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)
- Select Properties
- Select Disabled from the Startup type list
- Click Stop
- Select Apply to confirm changes.
- Click OK to exit the dialog box

On to Removing all Windows firewall files and registry entries

- Click on Start, then Run
- Type `cmd`, then press Ok
- Type the following command `sc delete SharedAccess`
- Wait for about ~10 seconds for the command to complete

Reinstalling the Windows Firewall Service

*Note: if the installer services fails, reboot into normal mode and try these steps again*

- Open another command prompt, or use the one already opened in the preceding steps.
- Type the following command in full in the command prompt, and hit the Enter key on your keyboard.
  `rundll32 setupapi,InstallHinfSection Ndi-Steelhead 132 netrass.inf`
- Wait for ~10 seconds for the command to complete.
- Next, to reset Windows Firewall, type the following command in full in the command prompt, and hit the Enter key on your keyboard.
  `netsh firewall reset`
- Close the Command Prompt, and open the Control Panel
- Double-click the Windows Firewall option.
- Click Yes when prompted by a message asking you if you want to start the Windows Firewall/Internet Connection sharing (ICS) service.

This *should* fix your Windows Firewall Problem, but if it doesn’t, you may try performing a System Restore, or re-installing the version of Windows Service Pack problem on your computer.